# Does anyone really say "SAYS" rather than "SEZ"?

Tags: pronunciation, irregular-verbs

I've just heard Labour party leader Jeremy Corbyn, at [10:13 here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/b080xh3p/prime-ministers-questions-26102016) (about a quarter of the way through *Prime Minister's Questions*, UK Parliament, Thurs 27 Oct) saying...

> *Amnesty International **SAYS,** and I quote, [blah blah, wot they **sed**]*

Apologies to anyone who can't access the video (it's a BBC link, which I suppose gets tricky if you're not a license payer), but obviously the point is he clearly says ***SAYS*** (/seɪz/), not ***SEZ*** (/sɛz/).

As it happens, while saying those words Corbyn is constantly looking down on what are presumably pre-written notes/quotes, so I'm inclined to suppose it's actually just a one-off enunciation error (because sometimes *reading and talking* is like [*walking and chewing gum!*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+and+chew+gum) :)

But seriously, does *anyone* talk like that today if they're not distracted by orthography?

---

I don't want to get bogged down in how non-native speakers affect things. I'm only really asking if there might perhaps be a surviving "dialectal pocket" of some kind (assuming the orthography represents an original pronunciation). Or could it be an "emergent usage", reflecting the general tendency to "regularise" irregular verbs?

Comment: Can't access that video, but I have heard "says" pronounced a number of different ways, by people who don't have a Midwestern US accent (the only "proper" accent there is).  Some Brits seem to pronounce it oddly, as do some Eurasians.

Comment: I certainly hear it, and not only from people reading aloud. But my inclination is to say it is northern - and Jeremy Corbyn certainly isn't a northerner. It is not something I would expect to hear from a sophisticated speaker - more from a child or young person reading aloud - but not only from such as them.

Comment: In the rarely-visited recesses of my Mancunian phonetic memory I can hear /seɪz/. I can't say I *never* say this. But normally I say /sɛz/.

Comment: Is anyone in the position to look it up in a dictionary that gives the pronunciation? I wonder if /seɪz/ is listed as an option? (Offtopic: in Fife, Scotland people say _says_ regardless of the pronoun: I says, he says, they says.. Very peculiar.)

Comment: ***How about "says" – does it sound like "sez" or "sayes"?*** It appears to be an open issue: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2010/oct/28/english-pronunciation-controversy

Comment: ...and note the past tense is not (or at least not any longer) spelled **sayed** but **said**.  So in that case, the spelling change followed the pronunciation change.

Comment: @GEdgar: I don't think the spelling and pronunciation are related: we get the same spelling pattern in *laid* and *paid,* which don't have shortened vowels.

Comment: @suməlic: If the spelling isn't relevant then the fact that Corbyn was obviously referring to ***written*** notes as he spoke would also be irrelevant. But that would surely imply some ***other*** reason for what stood out to me as a very unusual pronunciation. Not that I've spent *hours* listening to him, but I think I'd have noticed long ago if he *habitually* did this. A bit of unwanted "crosstalk" between visual and speech-generating cortex looks like the most likely explanation in this specific case. So I'm wondering if that's the *only* reason it ever happens today.

Comment: I've heard the unusual pronunciation used for emphasis (in England)

Comment: @Chris H: I can't see why anyone would suppose /seɪz/ was somehow more "emphatic" than /sɛz/, but surely if there were any substance to that line, you'd also sometimes encounter  /seɪd/ rather than /sɛd/ for the emphatic past tense. Do you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm not sure that I have heard the past tense treated that way, but this may be to do with how little I've heard it. Also when words are stressed a regional quirk can come out through much more strongly even when people's accents are more neutral, so it could be a combination of accent and emphasis

Comment: I'm British and I always pronounce it /seɪz/ rather than /sɛz/.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: Wow! Whereabouts in the country are you? Is this a personal quirk, or do other people around you do the same? Are you (and your parents) native speakers?

Comment: In 1950s Derbyshire the full version was very common, almost exaggerated, but was confined to people with Derbyshire accents as far as I can remember. It went with the detached 'g' at the end of 'ing' syllables as in sinGinG.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm fully British from North Cambridgeshire. I have heard people say it locally and would perhaps say that 30% of people pronounce it /seɪz/, although /sɛz/ is definitely in a majority.

Comment: That's the way my grandfather (Sheffield man) would have said it.

Comment: Corbyn was from Wiltshire and went to school in Shropshire. His speech probably reflects some of the West Country accents.

Comment: I'm from the East Midlands and I say 'says' from time to time. A lot will depend on context: Emphatic, "He ***says*** he is going to do it, but he never will." and more formally, "The following paragraph ***says*** "..."."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following extract from [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/05/sez-who.html) (2008) seems to suggest that "says" pronounced /seiz/ can still be heard:

> - Q: I hear BBC correspondents pronounce “says” with a long “a” to rhyme with “prays.” Why do Americans pronounce it like “sez” instead of like “pays,” “lays,” and other “ays” word that come to mind. Is it just a quirk of English?
> - A: The third-person singular of the verb “say” should be pronounced “sez” on both sides of the Atlantic, according to American and British dictionaries. But pompous broadcasting twits, especially across the pond, have never let standard pronunciations get in the way of on-air affectations.

According to the following extract from  ***[Wise  Words](http://www.abc.net.au/tv/canwehelp/txt/s2287064.htm)***, /seiz/ used to be the  standard pronunciation of "says" which  was gradually  replaced by the shorter /sɛz/. The former  appears to have survived as a non-standard dialectal form:

> - ***As the linguist Fidelholtz wrote back in 1975 — ‘Frequent words can do exceptional things’. The verb to 'say' is a good example of a mundane verb that is used a lot and that does exceptional things.*** ‘I say, you say, we say, they say’. There’s nothing peculiar here. It’s the so-called third person form that is the problem — this is where the verb falls out of kilter. In Standard English this is pronounced as ‘he/she/it sez’, and not ‘he/she/it says’. **So it’s the shortened version ‘sez’ that is standard; the full form ‘says’ is now considered non-standard, dialectal.**
> - ***The pronunciation shift from ‘says’ to ‘sez’ must have occurred some time ago — writers were already commenting on it as far back as the mid 1600s.***  Frequency has to be the trigger for the change here. I can think of no other explanation. The ‘he/she/it’ forms of verbs are used more often than other forms. And so the repetition of ‘says’ will have the effect of streamlining the way we articulate it. In other words, we know what we’re doing; we’ve done it so often, so we make short-cuts.
> - ***As in anything we do automatically, we get more efficient, faster and we decrease the size of whatever gestures are involved.***  In the case of speech, the transition between the sounds becomes more fluent — longer ‘says’ reduces to ‘sez’. You can see this also in the pronunciation of the form said, pronounced, in Standard English at least, with the same short vowel and not as you’d expect from the spelling (and as it was once pronounced) — ‘said’. Again you can imagine the regularity with which we produce phrases like ‘he said’/‘she said’/’it said’. ***Because we say it so often, we opt for a shorter route.***

(www.abc.net)

Comment: Wow I can't believe that when I first read this question I thought to myself, long says is just too hard to say, of course no one says it. But then prays, pays, lays...

Comment: @Unrelated  one of the preachers at speakers corner, that uses the pseudonym "bob the builder" on youtube, says it long, and others do too (perhaps mirroring him).

Answer (score 4):

- It seems that Jeremy Corbyn regularly pronounces “says” as /seɪz/, as witnessed by [this other video](https://twitter.com/BBCPolitics/status/1202892180160798720) (he repeats the word a number of times, e.g., at 1′31″ in the video clip, where it is unclear whether he is reading his notes at this point); as a matter of fact, I stumbled on this question because I [thought it was unusual](https://twitter.com/gro_tsen/status/1202922201202274306) so I googled “says seɪz sɛz”, which led me here.  Note that Corbyn pronounces “said” as /sɛd/ just a few seconds earlier, so I think we can rule out confusion due to the written form of the word.
- This doesn't seem to have been mentioned elsewhere in this thread, but the entry for “say” in the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* by J. C. Wells gives the result of a poll they conducted in 1998 among British English speakers concerning various words, with the result that “says” is pronounced /sɛz/ by 84% of respondents and /seɪz/ by 16% [the dictionary uses the transcription /e/ for the DRESS vowel, so they write “sez”, but I'm normalizing for consistency's sake].  They mark the pronunciation /seɪz/ with a ‘§’ symbol, meaning “BrE non-RP”.

Answer (score 0):

was Googling this as I was watching a BBC documentary about Anne Boleyn and the presenter , TRacy Borman, consistently used SAYS (like prays) not SEZ. Perhaps it's a  regional thing?

Answer (score 0):

It’s been my experience that many Canadians pronounce “says” as ”sāys”, especially in Windsor and Toronto. As an American I can say that in my 70 years, I’ve never heard an American do so. However, I often do listen to BBC radio, where it seems “sāys” is trending upward.

Comment: I do understand the ‘special’ characters needed are hard to type, but I'm afraid your `sāys` isn’t meaningful to the vast majority of our readers. Instead, the ꜱᴛᴀɴᴅᴀʀᴅɪᴢᴇᴅ way we spell those using the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) is  /seɪ/ for the base form *say* versus /seɪz/ where you just add a /z/ sound for the singular *says* but retain the close and often diphthongized vowel from FACE /feɪs/ — or else the /sɛz/ pronunciation with a totally different vowel, the more open vowel of DRESS /dɹɛs/.